# print without dialog box in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have to print a div section of asp.net page directly from printer without print dialog box,
it should be directly printed to client side default printer.

any help.

Thanks
Rajiv

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [JavaScript Print: Bypass Printer Dialog in IE and Firefox](http://justtalkaboutweb.com/2008/05/09/javascript-print-bypass-printer-dialog-in-ie-and-firefox/). However, there is no reliable method that will work on all major browsers/OSs.

Comment: its dislaying the print dialog box,

Comment: its displaying print dialog box, my requirement is that it should print 3 copy of the asp.page to default printer. if print dialog box is opened  user can change no of copies.